# PHP, mySQLi: store the value of an array element into a variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an SQL query which returns a single row as a result. This row contains only one column, an integer. I want to put this integer into a variable.

I execute my query and return the results of the query in an array as such:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

I would like to save the value of the single column of this single row into a variable, for example $age. How can this be done?

(This query will always return one row with one column, always an integer)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only one column and your query returns only one row, that means you'll get only one value, and since you're fetching an associative array, you can do the following and store it in a variable.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($row as $r) {
    $test = $r['age'];
}
```

However, since you're getting only one value out of that, you can just leave the result type out, and get `$test = $r[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_fetch_all` doesn't return a row. But set of rows.

```
$rows  = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$value = reset($rows[0]);
```

but it would be more logical to use a more suitable function:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$value = $row[0]; // here you go.
```